# 3 and 4 finger swipe stops working on MBP 13"

Tags: macbook

I have a MBP 13" running Snow Leopard with the 64-bit kernel.

The 3 and 4 finger swipe stops working randomly (I haven't pinpointed what causes it) and the only way to get it back is to do the SMC reset (shutdown, shift+control+option+power, wait, start, sleep light flashes).

Anybody else having this, and know of a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you go back to 32-bit kernel?

OS X is different from windows, in that the OS Kernel can run 32-bit and still support 64-bit applications and address more than 4GB of memory.

The problem with forcing SL to 64-bit mode (or rather why its not set by default) is that not all kexts (drivers) have been updated to run in 64-bit kernel.

Just a hunch.

Comment: While this works, and I'm going to accept the answer, I don't think it's really a valid fix. It's definitely a bug somewhere.